# Debug/Release Signature without Uninstall

Tags: android, apk, keystore, signature, verification

i recently uploaded an app to the play store and needed to sign the apk.

Now i have 2 keystores: for debugging and for releasing.

my problem is, that i cant install my app with eclipse when i have installed the play/release signed apk, i have always to uninstall it.

my question is, how others manage that?

is it possible to disable verification when installing via 'adb install' or somehow use the release key as debug key in eclipse? eclipse wont accept it because it hasnt the default debug alias and passwords.

metinkale38

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can define your custom (release) debug keystore as default.

In eclipse go to **Window** --> **Preference** --> **Android** --> **Build** copy the path of your keystore.

Comment: yes i know but that needs a keystore with default alias and password

Comment: so what, make a keystore once then you can use it every time

Comment: should i release an apk on play store with default alias+pw? that is not a proper solution!